# NW.js - webview - Angular is not defined error

Tags: angularjs, webview, nw.js

I want control external website using NW.js and webview, but anytime I try this I have error - Angular is not defined.

My source:

index.html

```
html...head...body...
<webview id="webview" name="webview" src="https://google.com/" allownw></webview>
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
...body...html
```

script.js

```
(function() {
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
var webview = document.getElementById("webview");

var tray = new gui.Tray({
    icon : 'assets/icon.png'
});

var menu = new gui.Menu();

menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
    type: 'normal',
    label: '▶️ Play',
    click: function() {
        webview.executeScript({code:"var player=angular.element(document.body).injector().get('player'); player.play();"});
    }
}));
tray.menu = menu;

}());
```

This code produce for me error: ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Note: Website google.com is only example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `nw.js` [docs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/webview%20Tag/):

> **loading local files in webview**
>
> Add the following permission to the manifest:

```
  "webview": {
     "partitions": [
        {
          "name": "trusted",
          "accessible_resources": [ "<all_urls>" ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

> and add 'partition="trusted"' attribute to the webview tag.

This is one reason why the `<script` tag cannot access your `../js/script.js` file. I also suggest using a non-relative path to your local file example: `chrome-extension://yourdomain/js/script.js` (and that it be relative to the root not 'up' a directory).

From google's [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), you can set `accessible_resources` to be specific patterns or files.

The `insertCss`, `setUserAgentOverride`, `permissionrequest` event, and especially `executeScript` from google's documentation will likely be of interest to you.

NOTE: you may not want to give that webview access to your nwjs context (`allownw`) because it can access *anything* that your program has access to.  This is especially true of both an external URL and http where [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) tampering or a third-party change could potentially cause someone to gain elevated access to the PC your application is running on.

For your example, I would keep the `script.js` outside of the webview and have it instrument the webview via script injection.